# Plot histogram for data from .txt file with names on x-axis and number on y axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I am new to programming, and I have tried plotting histograms for values. This is the first time I am trying to plot a histogram for names on the x axis. I went through the posts but found none helpful. I will greatly appreciate and be indebted to your help.

The data saved in a *.txt* file

Data

```
Seyfert1    112
Seyfert2    42
Quasars     131
QuasarsSeyfert1 46
Radiogalaxy    5
BLlacHP       39
Seyfert3    5
HeIIRegions 55
```

The code used is given below.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib

f = open('hist.txt','r')
x,y = np.loadtxt(f,unpack=True, usecols=[0,1])
plt.hist(y, bins=10, histtype='bar',facecolor = 'red',  rwidth=1.0)
plt.xlabel('Type of AGN',fontsize=15)
plt.ylabel('Number of galaxies',fontsize=15)
plt.title('Distribution of Type of active galaxies',fontsize=15)
plt.savefig('hist1.pdf',fmt='pdf')
plt.show()
```

I used the same for plotting the histogram with numbers. Not sure where I am going wrong.

Comment: Instead of a histogram, you probably want barplot: `plt.bar(x, y)`

Comment: Well, your first problem is `np.loadtxt` which default only want to read numbers.  You can try `x, y = np.loadtxt(f, unpack=True, usecols=[0, 1], dtype=str)` followed by `y = y.astype(int)`.  That way `x` will be an array of strings and `y` an array of integers.

Comment: It works but the names are overlapping. Is there any way to rectify this?
'

Comment: To rotate the tick labels by 20 degrees: `plt.tick_params(axis='x', labelrotation=20)`

Comment: This works but it cuts off the x-axis label. meaning I reduced the size of the label for each bar by using     plt.tick_params(axis='x', labelrotation=20, labelsize= 8)  but The x- axis label is cut off

Comment: You can afterwards call `plt.tight_layout()` to make the labels fit nicely inside the plot figure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of inputs from Mr.JohanC, I have found the answer to the question posted.

Here is the final program

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib


f = open('hist.txt','r')
x, y = np.loadtxt(f, unpack=True, usecols=[0, 1], dtype=str)
y = y.astype(int)
plt.bar(x, y)
plt.tick_params(axis='x', labelrotation=10, labelsize= 10)
plt.xlabel('Type of AGN',fontsize=15)
plt.ylabel('Number of galaxies',fontsize=15)
plt.title('Distribution of Type of active galaxies',fontsize=15)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig('hist_gal.pdf',fmt='pdf')
plt.show()
```